# Log likelihood from a lm function in R

Tags: r, economics

I would like to do a probit model using maximum log likelihood function. I already have a multinominal lm function in R and would like to start from there.

Here's the lm function which is a numeric (0,1) y variable on numeric and factor varibales:

ee2002ext$participe2 ~ enf18.f + enf3.f + ee2002ext$agd + ee2002ext$expot1 , data = ee2002ext, with(ee2002ext, s==1))

How can I proceed doing that ?

I did this for the moment:

```
    function(beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4, mu, sig) {
R=participe - enf3.f *beta1 - enf18.f*beta2 - age*beta3 - expot*beta4 - beta0 
R= suppressWarnings(dnorm(R, mu, sig))
-sum(R)
}
```

thanks,

Alexandre

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work out:
function(beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4, mu, sigma) {
R=participe - enf3.f*beta1 - enf18.f * beta2 - age *beta3 - expot * beta4 - beta0
R = suppressWarnings(dnorm(R, mu, sigma, log = TRUE))
-sum(R)
}

Comment: It's not easy to understand exactly what have you entered in R. Can you update your code in code block? You can see `{}` in the editor.

Comment: Ok i put it in the post.
sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can run a probit model by using glm().
In your case

```
reg <- glm(participe2 ~ enf18.f + enf3.f + agd + expot1 , data = ee2002ext, family = binomial(link = "probit"))
```

should work. 
To get a nice output use summary(reg) but you probably knew that already.